# Magento2: How can I get all orders from database tables

Tags: magento2, database, orders, table

I want to get all orders record from database.
How many tables I have to dump for . Kindly enlist the tables names here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dump for these tables for all orders records:

- sales_invoice
- sales_invoice_comment
- sales_invoice_grid
- sales_invoice_item
- sales_invoiced_aggregated
- sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
- sales_order
- sales_order_address
- sales_order_aggregated_created
- sales_order_aggregated_updated
- sales_order_grid
- sales_order_item
- sales_order_payment
- sales_order_status
- sales_order_status_history
- sales_order_status_state
- sales_order_tax
- sales_order_tax_item
- sales_shipment_item
- sales_shipping_aggregated
- sales_shipping_aggregated_order

> mysqldump -u root -p  sales_invoice sales_invoice_comment
>   sales_invoice_grid sales_invoice_item sales_invoiced_aggregated
>   sales_invoiced_aggregated_order sales_order sales_order_address
>   sales_order_aggregated_created sales_order_aggregated_updated
>   sales_order_grid sales_order_item sales_order_payment
>   sales_order_status sales_order_status_history sales_order_status_state
>   sales_order_tax sales_order_tax_item sales_shipment_item
>   sales_shipping_aggregated sales_shipping_aggregated_order > orders.sql

Answer (score 1):

We can get the all order details by this SQL query -

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name 
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
sales_creditmemo
sales_creditmemo_comment
sales_creditmemo_grid
sales_creditmemo_item
sales_invoice
sales_invoiced_aggregated
sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
sales_invoice_comment
sales_invoice_grid
sales_invoice_item
sales_order
sales_order_address
sales_order_aggregated_created
sales_order_aggregated_updated
sales_order_grid
sales_order_gst
sales_order_item
sales_order_item_gst
sales_order_payment
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_history
sales_order_status_label
sales_order_status_state
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item
sales_payment_transaction
sales_refunded_aggregated
sales_refunded_aggregated_order
sales_sequence_meta
sales_sequence_profile
sales_shipment
sales_shipment_comment
sales_shipment_grid
sales_shipment_item
sales_shipment_track
sales_shipping_aggregated
sales_shipping_aggregated_order > orderData.sql
```

I hope this will helps you to get only export the order details

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the following tables,
these are basically the tables storing and handling the orders data:

> sales_order  //responsible for all orders
>   sales_order_item //responsible for all order items associated to the order

Comment: just two tables have all orders data?

Comment: `sales_order_grid` is just the same with all the data in sale_order

Answer (score 0):

Below are tables related to order in Magento:

- `sales_order`;
- `sales_order_address`;
- `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
- `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
- `sales_order_grid`;
- `sales_order_item`;
- `sales_order_payment`;
- `sales_order_status_history`;
- `sales_order_tax`;
- `sales_order_tax_item`;

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove all test orders / data your best to run the below which will do this.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

# Clean order history
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;

# Clean order infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;

# Clean cart infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

# Reset indexes (if you want your orders number start back to 1
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_invoice_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_shipment_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

sales_order stores main order data

Answer (score 0):

You can get the all the order related tables using below query

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly sales_creditmemo sales_creditmemo_comment sales_creditmemo_grid sales_creditmemo_item sales_invoice sales_invoice_comment sales_invoice_grid sales_invoice_item sales_invoiced_aggregated sales_invoiced_aggregated_order sales_order sales_order_address sales_order_aggregated_created sales_order_aggregated_updated sales_order_grid sales_order_item sales_order_payment sales_order_status sales_order_status_history sales_order_status_label sales_order_status_state sales_order_tax sales_order_tax_item sales_payment_transaction sales_refunded_aggregated sales_refunded_aggregated_order sales_sequence_meta sales_sequence_profile sales_shipment sales_shipment_comment sales_shipment_grid sales_shipment_item sales_shipment_track sales_shipping_aggregated sales_shipping_aggregated_order > OrderData.sql
```